# Seeking Tutorial for Boundless Web App Builder?

Tags: qgis, boundless-suite, references, boundless-web-app-builder

Anyone know where is I can get tutorial for Boundless Web App Builder with QGIS for Open Geo Suite? (in video or pdf format).

I had tried to search on Google, and tutorial mostly for ArcGIS.

Comment: How do I start building a web app using Qgis ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are referring to the [Boundless Web App Builder](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/)?

There is a Tutorial right from the source: [Building Openlayers3 WebApp](http://boundlessgeo.com/2015/06/building-openlayers-3-web-app-without-writing-code/)

They also have a whole section of tutorials:

- [Mapping French Schools](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/qgis/webappbuilder/tutorials/schools/index.html)
- [Mapping Paris Bakeries](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/qgis/webappbuilder/tutorials/bakeries/index.html)
- [Mapping Songs about Madrid](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/qgis/webappbuilder/tutorials/songs/index.html)
- [Mapping Fire Events](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/qgis/webappbuilder/tutorials/fires/index.html)

If you prefer PDF over a HTML based documentary you can build it with Sphinx - the complete documentation (and information about the build process) can be found on their [Github repository](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/tree/master/docs).

Comment: None of these are in the `video or pdf format` requested by the OP.

Comment: @nmtoken The complete documentation is created with Sphinx and can be found [on Github](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/tree/master/docs). PDFs can be created from there, as well as a local HTML copy of the docs.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your answer accordingly, as comments are not the best way of adding additional information